# Some troubles with deploy rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I created rails application, it works great in development environment, but now  I want to deploy it. I have a vps with passenger and nginx, I deployed rails application with static pages, but now application needs database. 
Which best way to clone structure from development base and then deploy it?
Please give any guides to deploy application? 
I use (ubuntu 10.04_64, rails 3.0.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a copy of your development database (structure and data).

If you are using a sqlite3 database in development (which you probably are), then on the server (after you've deployed) make a copy of it and name it production.sqlite3

```
cp development.sqlite3 production.sqlite3
```

This will copy the structure and data of your development database.  If its a static site however, you could do this on the development machine before you deploy.

Let me know if you need instructions to do this for mysql (or any other database) and I will edit this answer.

Comment: But I want to create only structure of database.

Answer (score 0):

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

or I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Command `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production` creates empty file and I get error `db/production.sqlite3 already exists`(but before command file "production.sqlite3" didn`t exist), evidently `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` doesn`t work.